# Why can't i set Tensorflow properly for use on Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I went to anaconda prompt and typed the following:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

the in the jupyter notebook i typed:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

what i got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError: <class '_frozen_importlib._ModuleLockManager'> returned a result with an error set

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import
```

Comment: What versions of python, tensorflow and numpy do you have if you run a pip freeze?

Comment: It is better not to run `pip install` on anaconda env (here is why https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment). Can you try to install tensorflow through `conda install`? If not, which python version and which tf version are you using?

Comment: I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518632/importerror-numpy-core-multiarray-failed-to-import) should fix it.