# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket' even though I installed pip install websocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I am trying to run some code that has 'import websocket' however I am getting the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'`

I have Python 3.7.3 and I am running in Spyder (if that makes a difference).

So from other questions/answers I found on here, in my cmd I ran `pip install websocket` and then also `pip install websocket-client` when the first one didn't run.

I am still getting the `ModuleNotFoundError`. Does it matter the location/folder of the code or where I install the pip command in cmd?

My python code starts with these import statements:

```
import json
import websocket
import traceback
import helper
import ssl
import time as time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

In cmd I ran:

```
C:\Users\myname>pip install websocket
```

and also:

```
C:\Users\myname>pip install websocket-client
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "C:/Users/micki/Downloads/Derbit-Volatility-Visulization-master/Derbit-Volatility-Visulization-master/Volatility Surface Class.py", line 2, in <module>
    import websocket

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websocket'
```

Comment: Can you try `pip3 install websocket`?  Sometimes you have an old pip left over from python2.

Comment: Do you have Python2 installed on the same machine?

Comment: *Always* use `python3 -m pip install` to avoid the possibility of mismatch issues.

Comment: Did you install Spyder via Anaconda or Conda?

Comment: @jacob I have installed Spyder via Anaconda

Comment: @sophros I do not think I have Python2 installed. But how can I confirm?

Comment: @user1781336 Yep, Anaconda does not include websocket-client from the factory, as it's primarily geared toward data science and the like. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, as you did not cover how you installed and are using Spyder, though I think it is probably an issue with your environment. You might also find that you are missing the module "helper" as well. There's two easy options as follows:

1. If you installed and are using Spyder via conda or anaconda, follow their documentation on installing websocket-client to the correct environment found [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/websocket-client).
2. The second option (the preferred option IMHO, as you can use any IDE or text editor going forward), regardless of how you installed Spyder, would be to create a python virtual environment `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`, pip install all your dependencies in said environment, then link Spyder's interpreter to the interpereter that was installed when you made the environment. In Spyder, go to Tools -> Preferences -> Python interpreter -> check the "Use the following Python interpreter:" radio button and enter the path to the interpreter from the environment you just created. For reference, see docs on making and using a python venv [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments).

Comment: I'm also curious what is the difference between websocket and websockets (with and "s")? Is there a difference?

Comment: @user1781336 Yes, `import websocket` will import [websocket-client](https://pypi.org/project/websocket_client/), while `import websockets` will import [websockets](https://pypi.org/project/websockets/). They're both APIs for harnessing the lower level functions of the websocket protocol. To understand the exact differences, you should read the docs. If you come up with something, post a question and answer it yourself to inform the community, as I am curious myself.

Comment: @user1781336 Did the answer help/work? If so, mark it as accepted; if not, clarify further...

Answer (score 0):

If the `websocket` and `websocket-client` doesn't work, try:

```
pip install websocket_client
```

Comment: Be careful when using pip and conda together!!!! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
sudo pip install websocket-client
```