# conda list -n myenv shows package that I cannot uninstall

Tags: python, pyqt5, conda

I have a conda (4.7.12) environment called `py36` (python3.6). When running `conda list -n py36`, it shows that I have pyqt5 (5.15.0) installed:

[image: conda says pyqt5 is installed]

I want to uninstall this package. However, when I run `pip uninstall pyqt5` or `pip uninstall PyQt5` with the `py36` environment activated, it says the package is not installed:

[image: pip says it's not.]

Which one is correct? Is PyQt5 installed or not? I cannot test with code because I am reinstalling Qt5 on this machine.

Comment: This could happen if `pip` is resolved to somewhere other than your environment. What does `which pip` show? More robust would be `conda run -n py36 python -m pip uninstall pyqt5`.

Answer (score -1):

Just go into a python console and try

```py
import PyQt5
```

and you see if it is there or not!

Comment: Hi DaveR, thanks for your response. However, this still leaves me mistified as to why conda and pip are contradicting each other whether or not PyQt5 is installed.

Comment: It could be that `pip` is referring to a different python or python environment, so you should check that too. In general avoid using `pip` and `conda` together as they are prone to errors as you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment