# JupyterLab Windows 10 issues after updating to Anaconda 2021.05

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, windows-10, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently made a **clean** installation for Anaconda 2021.05.

After pip installing JupyterLab extensions and other libraries,

I observe major issues whenever I launch either a

> jupyter notebook

> jupyter lab

After a few minutes of work, my session crashes with the following message.
Any ideas where to look for debugging?

```
[I 2021-05-28 09:01:37.987 ServerApp] Saving file at /Untitled.ipynb
[I 2021-05-28 09:03:42.862 ServerApp] Kernel started: 1f6f770d-1093-46c5-897a-e25553d49593
Exception in thread Tornado selector:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Softwares\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Softwares\Anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Softwares\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 551, in _run_select
    rs, ws, xs = select.select(to_read, to_write, to_write)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: "After pip installing" - did you use pip install in a conda environment? It is likely that this broke your installation (i.e. leading to a mix up of conda and pip installed versions). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment. I recommend starting a new clean environment and only using `conda install`. Most of JupyterLab extensions are available on conda-forge channel of conda. If you however hope someone will be able to hint a solution for this broken environment, I recommend including a `pip list` output.

Comment: Thank you @krassowski for your response. Will try it out.