# Unable to install tidyverse package for r kernel in jupyter

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, tidyverse, jupyter-irkernel

I have recently installed **Anaconda** and also **enabled r kernel** by using `conda install -c r r-irkernel` which i took reference from: https://kyleake.medium.com/how-to-install-r-in-jupyter-with-irkernel-in-3-steps-917519326e41 .

Now from `jupyter notebook` when I try to **install** `tidyverse` package I get this error regarding `jsonlite`:

```
Warning message:
"package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.6.3"
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse' in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 namespace 'jsonlite' 1.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.7.2 is required
Traceback:

1. library("tidyverse")
2. tryCatch({
 .     attr(package, "LibPath") <- which.lib.loc
 .     ns <- loadNamespace(package, lib.loc)
 .     env <- attachNamespace(ns, pos = pos, deps, exclude, include.only)
 . }, error = function(e) {
 .     P <- if (!is.null(cc <- conditionCall(e))) 
 .         paste(" in", deparse(cc)[1L])
 .     else ""
 .     msg <- gettextf("package or namespace load failed for %s%s:\n %s", 
 .         sQuote(package), P, conditionMessage(e))
 .     if (logical.return) 
 .         message(paste("Error:", msg), domain = NA)
 .     else stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
 . })
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. value[[3L]](cond)
6. stop(msg, call. = FALSE, domain = NA)
```

seems like `jsonlite' 1.6 is already loaded, but >= 1.7.2 is required` is the problem, so when I try to manually install `jsonlite` then I get this issue:

```
install.packages("jsonlite")


package 'jsonlite' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning message:
"cannot remove prior installation of package 'jsonlite'"Warning message in file.copy(savedcopy, lib, recursive = TRUE):
"problem copying C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\R\library\00LOCK\jsonlite\libs\x64\jsonlite.dll to C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\R\library\jsonlite\libs\x64\jsonlite.dll: Permission denied"Warning message:
"restored 'jsonlite'"

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\viny\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpADyCWE\downloaded_packages
```

so how can i install `tidyverse package` in `jupyter notebook`?

Comment: Do not mix `conda install` and `install.packages`. Only use `install.packages` if the package is not on conda. tidyverse is on conda, so you should now `remove.packages("tidyverse")` and then `conda install -c r r-tidyverse` (see https://anaconda.org/r/r-tidyverse). You may be also interested in learning about conda-forge channel which provides much more R packages.

Comment: If this works I will add it as an answer, but not sure how you installed `tidyverse` (you only show that you cannot import it), so for now just leaving the above as a general advice.

Comment: Thanks @krassowski, the method that you have shown worked perfectly. I was actually following the process from the website that showed installation process as well and in there, they were using `install.packages()`. So I too did same as this is also followed in R. But thanks again for showing me the correct way. Please add this as an answer & i will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix `conda install` and `install.packages`. Only use `install.packages` if the package is not on conda. tidyverse is on conda (see anaconda.org/r/r-tidyverse), so you should now `remove.packages("tidyverse")` and then `conda install -c r r-tidyverse`.

You may be also interested in learning about conda-forge channel which provides much more R packages.

If you are also using Python, this also apply to mixing pip install and conda install - doing so will break your installations in the ways that are difficult to imagine (see [Is that a bad idea to use conda and pip install on the same environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment)). Largely this can be attributed to conda using its own mechanisms for handling library/package paths which and not interacting great with other distribution systems.

Comment: Thanks alot @krassowski for helping me on this. In the past I have also done the mistake of mixing `pip install` and `conda install` in `python`. Now that I have learnt my lesson, so will be careful in future. Thanks again :))

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error when trying to load tidyverse in Jupyter Notebook, but the other answer here did not work for me. The following site helped me:

[https://jonathansoma.com/everything/r/r-no-package-called-library/#:~:text=The%20problem,-For%20example%2C%20you&text=This%20might%20be%20happening%20because,to%20install%20the%20tidyverse%20package](https://jonathansoma.com/everything/r/r-no-package-called-library/#:%7E:text=The%20problem,-For%20example%2C%20you&text=This%20might%20be%20happening%20because,to%20install%20the%20tidyverse%20package)

Jonathan's site mentions that the error can occur when you have multiple versions or R installed on your computer. If the the R kernel that Python uses differs from the one that R uses, that can cause an error. Running the following code in R Studio and then restarting Jupyter notebook fixed my issue:

```r
install.packages('IRkernel', repos = 'http://cran.us.r-project.org')
IRkernel::installspec()
```