# How to update flask from version 1.1.2 to version 2.0 on anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

When I install the latest version of anaconda distribution, it comes with flask version 1.1.2. However, I need to install flask version 2.0. How can I install flask version 2.0 (in the base environment) while keeping other existing packages installed such as sklearn and numpy, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First do `conda activate base`,

Then you can either do `pip install flask==2.0.0` or `conda install -c conda-forge flask==2.0.0`. Both are okay as long as you do conda activate base first.

You should consider creating a new environment for your project and not mess with the base environment.

First do `conda create -n newname`, then `conda activate newname`.

Then you can do `conda install -c conda-forge numpy pandas sklearn flask==2.0.0`, you can also do `pip install numpy pandas sklearn flask==2.0.0`. You can install everything you need in one line.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. However, the reason I'm not creating a new environment is that if I create a new one, all necessary packages (such as numpy, sklearn, etc.) are not automatically installed in it. Is there a way to automatically install these packages without explicitly installing them one by one?

Comment: There’s a quick way, I’ll update my answer, it’s better this way, so you don’t mess up the base, you just separate the package names with a space.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

```
conda activate base
conda remove flask
conda install -c conda-forge flask
```

Line 1: to activate your `base` virtual environment

Line 2: in order to avoid any conflict, remove flask 1.1.2

line 3: install the latest flask version via the channel conda-forge (2.0.1 as for now)

If you want the 2.0.0 you should do this: `conda install -c conda-forge flask=2.0.0`

**Explanations:**

- Channels:

conda uses channels (like repositories where the packages are stored). By default, the channel is the `anaconda` channel. So, if you installed flask with `conda install flask` that is the same as if you did `conda install -c anaconda flask`. And from this page (https://anaconda.org/anaconda/flask) you can see that the actual version  on this channel is `1.1.2`.

- About the update part:

In general, to update all your packages in a virtual environment, you first have to activate your virtual environment with `conda activate [virtual_environment_name]` and then `conda update --all`.

But as you can see from the previous link, on the default channel (anconda), the latest version is `1.1.2`, so, strictly speaking, you **can't** update flask to a version greater than `1.1.2`.

But, because on the `conda-forge` channel the latest version is -as for now- `2.0.1`, if you install flask from this channel, you will get flask `2.0.1`.

- Using pip in a Conda environment:

An other option mentionned by @anarchy too is to use `pip install flask=2.0.0` but you should avoid that. See: https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment and
[Is that a bad idea to use conda and pip install on the same environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment).

- About not using the `base` environment directly:

And in order to have a clean workspace, it's a good practice to create a virtual environment other than the `base` environment for your projects. You can create and then activate a new environment named for example "myenv" like this:

```
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
```

And so the complete code would be:

```
conda create -n myenv
conda activate myenv
conda install -c conda-forge flask
```

And finally if you want to install the latest versions of other packages like numpy and sklearn, you should use conda-forge too:

```
conda install -c conda-forge scikit-learn 
conda install -c conda-forge numpy
```