# No module named 'matplotlib.typing'

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotnine

I am receiving an error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.typing'` with this bit of code:

```
from plotnine import *

(ggplot(the, aes(x='Trial', y='Weights', colour='Cues')) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_colour_manual(values=['#1f78b4','#b2df8a','#fb9a99','#e31a1c','#ae017e']))
```

I am running Anaconda on macOS:

- `conda 23.7.4`
- `plotnine                  0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi`
- `matplotlib                3.7.1           py311hecd8cb5_1`

This, however, works on my older machine with all the same specs but `plotnine` being `0.12.4`.

Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: What's your python version ?

Comment: Type hinting was introduced to Matplotlib at v3.8, so one option is to upgrade your Matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plotnine` needs to be downgraded:

```
pip install plotnine==0.12.4
```

Comment: You seem to be working with Conda.  Conda and pip often don't work together well.  See e.g. [Is it a bad idea to use conda and pip install on the same environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134588/is-that-a-bad-idea-to-use-conda-and-pip-install-on-the-same-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Try running this code

```
`conda install -c conda-forge plotnine=0.12.4`
```